# How does database replication work conceptually?

Tags: database, synchronization, replication, database-replication

I would like to understand how database replication works conceptually. I know that databases have their own log (e.g., the OpsLog in MongoDB), but most information you can find on the web is about setting up replication, not how it works.

I'm also not interested in understanding how MS SQL Server or MySQL does replication specifically. It's more like, I would like to grasp the basic ideas and concepts of replication.

Unfortunately, I don't know the terms to look for, so if I look for

> How does database replication work?

or

> database replication conceptually

I end up with hundreds of websites explaining how to make replication work for database X, but I can't come up with an explanation on the conceptual level.

Any hints? (Please note that of course I would be happy about a detailed answer, but even a small hint on what to search the web for would be great!)

PS: For the beginning, even an explanation of how one-way replication works would be helpful.

PPS: Since [How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work?rq=1) has been a valid question, I hope that mine is valid, too, and does not get closed or downvoted for being "too broad".

Comment: This might be an interesting read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14226/repoverview.htm#CJAFJIBB It might be Oracle specific but it will describe a large number of configurations and concepts.